# null column in protection from sql injection

Tags: php, null, sql-injection

hi i am having a contact form in my website where user can optionaly fill some of the fields and after click on submit button data save in to the database all of this worked fine until i decide to sanitize my code from sql injection  as i mentioned at first before trying to sanitize it from sql injection it worked properly as i showed in below code

```html
<form method="Post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="name" />name
        <select dir="rtl" style="width: 173px;" name="case" >
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>اplease choose</option>
        <option  value='rent'>rent</option>
        <option  value='sell'>sell</option>
          </select >
          <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value='a'>apartment<br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
<?php
include("config.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

        $date_clicked = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    }
    //insert to database
     $insert =mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO $db_table VALUES (to simplify code i do not write this part)");

    }
    ?>
```

now i have to fill all the dropdown lists and checkboxes otherwise it gives error "column '' can not be null". also i can not insert date and time into database it gives the same error. here is my code when i protect it fron sql injection:

```html
 <form method="Post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" />name
    <select dir="rtl" style="width: 173px;" name="case" >
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>اplease choose</option>
    <option  value='rent'>rent</option>
    <option  value='sell'>sell</option>
      </select >
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value='a'>apartment<br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <?php
     include("config.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

        $date_clicked = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    //insert to database
    $query = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO $db_table VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        /* bind parameters for markers */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $query, "ssss", $_POST[name],$_POST['check1'],$_POST['case'],$_POST['date_clicked']);
    // execute query
    if ( mysqli_stmt_execute($query) ) {
      echo "Successfully inserted " . mysqli_affected_rows($connect) . " row";
    } else {
      echo "Error occurred: " . mysqli_error($connect);
    }

    }


    ?>
```

please help me

Comment: `$_POST[name]` should be `$_POST["name"]`, is this in your original code or just a typo in the code you pasted in the question?

Comment: no in the original one it is $_POST["name"]

Comment: Make sure there aren't any PHP warnings. For example, `$_POST["check1"]` would only be set if the checkbox is set so you'd get a PHP warning there which would make the rest of the code in that line misbehave. Also, make sure your database table allows nulls in the fields that are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your variables exist. This is necessary because your checkbox, for example, will be null if not checked and that could be a problem for the table you are using. You could set defaults and then insert it.

```
$name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$check1 = !empty($_POST['check1']) ? $_POST['check1'] : '';
$case = !empty($_POST['case']) ? $_POST['case'] : '';
$date_clicked = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `$db_table` (`name`, `check1`, `case`, `date_clicked`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $check1, $case, $date_clicked);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer dropdown lists and checkboxes are work fine now but date and time variable does not work properly and only save 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in the database. i do now know why. can you help me?

Comment: I just realized that date is generated and isn't coming from the form. I revised my answer.